# What is 'but' in "nothing but"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, conjunctions, ambiguity, parts-of-speech

**"It did nothing but make us ridiculous."**

It means : *"It did nothing but It did make us ridiculous."*

Here, 'but' seems to be a **conjunction**.

But I know, 'but' is a **preposition** (meaning 'except') in the phrase 'nothing but'!

Again, if 'but' is a preposition, the verb following it should be in -ing from. But here the verb is in the base from - 'make'!

Then, what is the parts of speech of 'but' in the phrase "nothing but"?

Comment: _But_ means _except_ here too. Your sentence means _It did nothing except make us ridiculous_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, how can the base from of a verb [make] be used after a preposition (but/except)?

Comment: The preposition "but" can take every kind of non-finite clause as complement, just as "except" can.

Comment: I.E., the verb itself is not the complement of "but". It's the clause containing the verb.

Comment: @BillJ, When does the preposition 'but' take infinitival non-finite clause? When does it take gerundial non-finite clause? Please clarify it with examples.

Comment: _There is nothing any of us can do except/but be cautious_ (bare infinitival);  _I don't intend to do anything except/but to wait for news_ (_to_-infinitival);  _I can't think what to advise except/but staying home_ (gerund-participial). In those examples, "but" is semantically close to "except.

Comment: Incidentally, the PPs are licensed by the clauses containing them. This means that the verb preceding the PP may be instrumental in determining the form of the non-finite clause.

Comment: @BillJ, What is meant by the PPs?

Comment: PP = preposition phrase. (For future reference, the other abbreviations are NP=noun phrase, AdjP=adjective phrase, AdvP=adverb phrase, DP=determinative phrase, VP=verb phrase).

Comment: @BillJ, Here, PP is 'but' or 'except' ? Someone is saying that 'Nothing but' is an adverb phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the others mentioned, the 'but' in 'nothing but' is basically a synonym for 'except'. So the sentence would be 'It did nothing except make us ridiculous'. Using 'but' instead of 'except' does not change the meaning of the sentence whatsoever. English speakers use 'but' as that is a more common word and easier to say.

Comment: How should I know whether 'but' takes infinitival or gerundial nonfinite clause after it?

Comment: It's one of those things that you just learn by speaking the language.

Comment: I would like to know if there is some grammatical rule about it.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to help you with that. I'm sorry